Multiple Date Pickers - disable selected dates
I'm using 'MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI' http://luca.lauretta.info/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/  which as far as I can tell uses jQuery-ui Datepicker.
On my site I've got 3 date pickers configured on input fields A, B & C allowing users to select multiple dates per field.
If a user selects a date in picker A, then it shouldn't be available in picker B or C.
If they remove that date in picker A, then it should become available for pickers B & C.
multiDatesPicker is being called as follows:
$('#dates' + i).multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "d MM",
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 365,
    onSelect: function(date) {
    },
});

Does anyone how how to achieve the above ?
Thanks

Using addDisabledDates: disabledDates works, but only when the plugin is first loaded. If more dates are added to disabledDates, they aren't being disabled.

I would add/remove the date(s) to an Array and then use the BeforeShow option to disable those dates in the other calendars. Not sure if you can use a Function with addDisabledDates where it return all the currently selected dates.

Strike the Function option, does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/om7hu4ga/3/

Consider the following Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/om7hu4ga/23/
JavaScript
$("[id^='mdp-demo-']").multiDatesPicker({
  onSelect: function (dt, ui) {
    var that = $(this)
    if (that.is("#mdp-demo-a")) {
      console.log(that.multiDatesPicker("getDates"))
      $("[id^='mdp-demo-']")
        .not(that)
        .multiDatesPicker({
          addDisabledDates: that.multiDatesPicker("getDates"),
        });
    }
  },
})

This updates the addDisabledDates setting as each date is Added or Removed.
